# Connect-MgGraph without user interaction

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I want to connect MgGraph without user interaction.

Normally we use normal command like `Connect-MgGraph`

I found that we can do that by passing `certificate` as parameter. From powershell, there are many scripts but unable to get any from Graph api.

How to create certificate from Microsoft graph Api?

TIA

Comment: you cant create a certificate from graphAPI. you have to have a certificate which you want to use as secret. you must upload this certificate to a service principal as secret. later you can use this certificate to authenticate as service principal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**

Open an admin PowerShell prompt and run the below command to create the self-assign certificate

```
$pwd = "Your Password"
$thumb = (New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "script.mydomain.com" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"  -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddMonths(24)).Thumbprint
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "cert:\localmachine\my\$thumb" -FilePath c:\user\cert.pfx -Password $pwd
```

where

- "Your Password" should be complex.
- NotAfter (Get-Date).AddMonths(24) here we are setting the expiring date for the certificate, now + 24 months in this case. Adjust as required
- “c:\user\cert.pfx” with where you would like a copy of the certificate saved

**Step 2**

Before we can upload the certificate to Azure, we need to convert the certificate to Base64. You could use the certificates MMC snap-in as we marked the certificate as exportable or run the below PowerShell,

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("C:\user\cert.pfx", "Your Password")
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData()) | Out-File c:\user\cert_base64.crt
```

where "c:\user\cert_base64.crt" is your new base64 certificate path

**Step 3**

upload certificate to azure portal
[image]

**Step 4**

then copy the thumbprint , we will use in below command
[image]

**Step 5**

## Connect to Azure

```
$tenantID = "<Your Tenant ID>"
$applicationID = "<Your Application ID>"
$thumbprint = "<Your Certificate Thumbprint>"
 
Connect-MgGraph -ClientID $applicationID -TenantId $tenantID - CertificateThumbprint $thumbprint
```

## Ger all Azure AD Users /

```
Get-MgUser
```

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Please change variable name `$pwd` into something else, because in PowerShell that is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#pwd) representing the full path of the current directory location for the current PowerShell runspace.

Comment: This is a very nice answer, thanks for sharing tho I agree with Theo. It's worth changing `$pwd` to a different variable name to not confuse future readers

Comment: Thanks for your response  , the password should be complex , that's why i added the sample password , and mentioned below , but sorry if that confused you , i will edit my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To do certificate based authentication, you need app id, tenant id and certificate thumprint. So, you need register app in Azure AD and then authenticate the app using certificate.
To create self-signed certificates by yourself, the best option would be PowerShell.
`$Certificate=New-SelfSignedCertificate –Subject testing.com -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My`

Then you can export the created certificate to store it in your local machine for further use.

`Export-Certificate -Cert $Certificate -FilePath "C:\$certname.cer"`

Instead of manually performing these steps, you can  automate the Azure AD app registration process, such as creating an Azure AD app, generating certificates, and granting admin consent. You can download the script from: https://blog.admindroid.com/connect-to-microsoft-graph-powershell-using-certificate/